# Можно ли каким-то образом подключить свой css к iframe ?

Tags: css, вконтакте

Можно ли к `iframe` у виджета комментариев подключить свой css?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нельзя. Что загружено с одного домена, неподконтрольно контенту из другого.

Comment: тут @sergiks прав;)

Answer (score 0):

**Ответ не в тему. Невнимательно прочитал вопрос.**

Если постараться то все можно сделать.
Если фреймы имеют один origin, то значит Вы, скорее всего (если можете менять стили), владелец обоих сайтов, отображаемых в родителе и в фрейме. А значит на странице с фреймом Вы можете получать пуш уведомления, через которые Вы запросто можете отправлять стили css и с помощью обработчика на стороне фрейма применять их к элементам.

Есть еще масса способов, но это уже совсем другая история..)

Comment: Вопрос про виджет ВК. Павел Дуров, перелогиньтесь.

Comment: * **у виджета комментариев**

 * тэг **вконтакте**

Comment: @sergiks, @eicto прошу прощения за вечернуюю усталость.) Но я хоть попытался помочь.)

Comment: Ок, тоже попытаюсь помочь. Хакнуть ограничение Same Origin можно через установку пользователем расширения для браузера, которое вы напишите. Например, для переназначения стилей виджета ВК.

Это небезопасно, не практично, всех посетителей сайта не заставишь устанавливать непойми-что, но **в принципе** заданный вопрос решает.